# Some test categories not getting executed in azure devops release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipline with 3 stages and each stage has some testcategories to execute like below.
Stage-1 TestCategory=functionality_1|functionality_2|functionality_3|functionality_4|functionality_5
Stage-2 TestCategory=functionality_6|functionality_7|functionality_8|functionality_9
stage-3 TestCategory=functionality_10|functionality_11|functionality_12

After pipline execution I could see that test scripts having testcategory functionality_3, functionality_9 and functionality_10 are not executed.

Total testscripts count not matching with test results in each stage.
Also some test scripts are getting executed twice.
I am using MS hosted agent, Mstest framework.

I have checked all tags , test category, testmethod, testclass all looks ok.
When run that specific category individually in pipline then test scripts run but not in batch.
Can someone guide what could be the issue? Let me know any more details required.

Answer (score 0):

In devops pipeline (test assembly task) as well as in command line need to pass below format which will execute all test categories and no one is skipped.

```
TestCategory=functionality_1|TestCategory=functionality_2|TestCategory=functionality_3|TestCategory=functionality_4|TestCategory=functionality_5
```

My all the test scripts are getting executed now.